# Конструктор в контроллерах Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

**Всем доброго дня!**

Наверняка, вы знакомы с такой классной вещью в Rails как Layouts. Если приложение должно иметь единый интерфейс, то вполне достаточно одного такого Layout`а -`application.html`, который, собственно, по умолчанию и используется, если нет ничего другого, и конфигурация осталась неизменной. Но вот если в контроллерах использовать привычный Ruby-конструктор:

```
def initialize
...
end
```

то лэйаут не используется. Собственно, почему так?

**Спасибо)**

Comment: Ответ совершенно навскидку - а вы super initialize внутри писать пробовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сорри, отвык уже от Ruby. Я имею в виду следующее:

```
class Parent
  def initialize
    puts "Parent"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def initialize
    super
  end
end

puts Child.new
```

Я предполагаю что в Rails как его там ActionController в своём initialize как раз устанавливает layout и поэтому предлагаю вам это проверить: просто напишите

```
def initialize
  super

  # А здесь код, который вы хотите исполнить в своём конкретном контроллере
end
```

Comment: Да, все верно, проблема в этом. Почему-то я даже не предположил ,что часть функционала может быть в конструкторе(инициализаторе) родительского класса. Ваш ответ мне помог, так что большое спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Удачи!